# Are all finite graphs that cannot embed in any non-orientable surface planar?

Tags: topological-graph-theory, non-orientable-surfaces

There exist graphs which don't have a 2-cell embedding in any non-orientable surface (take $C_n$, for example). Is it true that any finite graph with this property must be planar?

Define the non-orientable genus of a graph $G$, $\tilde{\gamma}(G)$, as the minimum non-orientable genus among all surfaces in which $G$ can be 2-cell embedded (With $\tilde{\gamma}(G)=0$ if $G$ is one of the graphs described above). If $e$ is an edge in $G$, does this imply that $\tilde{\gamma}(G\setminus\{e\})\leq \tilde{\gamma}(G)$?

Comment: If you start with an arbitrary graph, how is a 2-cell embedding for it defined?

Comment: An embedding for which every face is homeomorphic to the unit disc.

Comment: I see. But if one is not considering a particular planar embedding then how can one define the set of "faces" of the graph?